# Angular material sidenav hover

Tags: angular, angular-material, hover, sidenav

I am trying to build an Angular Sidebar. Currently, it is having a toggle effect which means, when we click it, it will collapse. If it is collapsed, it will expand. Now I am trying to expand only the item which gets hover. I need some help with this.

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8zy3pi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SOF, please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] of your issue on https://stackblitz.com.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution:

I have made changes in your left-menu-component.html for that hover effect as you asked for.here is the link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w1b2ho?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fleft-menu%2Fleft-menu.component.html

Comment: your example loads then throws an error: Error in src/theme.scss
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'write$1' on null

Comment: this is awesome! Thank you, I have used it in my project now. Just a small point that the button at the button causes animation thrashing when you click it while your mouse still hovers over it.